# Mongodb doesn't load crypto | ssl libraries during startup

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I am trying to use the latest mongodb binary bits, but for some reason it doesn't load the crypto | ssl libraries.

```
ldd bin/mongod
bin/mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by bin/mongod)
bin/mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by bin/mongod)
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff186f4000)
libssl.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f08a48c1000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f08a44e6000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f08a42dd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f08a40d9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f08a3dd5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f08a3ace000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f08a38b8000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f08a369a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f08a32d4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f08a4b3d000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is typically received when the enterprise dependencies have not been installed prior to startup of mongo.

This is documented here - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/#install-mongodb-enterprise-from-tarball